# Query two tables - return Items that are not in both

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like this :

TableA

```
Id | ProjectId | JobId
```

TableB

```
Id | Title
```

I want to write a query returning TableB Ids that are not in TableA with `ProjectId = 2`.

I've written a query like

```
Select B.Id 
From TableB B 
Right Join TableA A On B.Id = A.JobId 
Where B.JobId Is Null And A.ProjectId = 2
```

But it returns zero output.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `EXISTS` here:

```
SELECT b.Id
FROM TableB b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA a WHERE a.JobId = b.Id AND a.ProjectId = 2);
```

Reading in English terms, the above says to select every `Id` in `TableB` such that we cannot find an equal `Id` in `TableA` whose `ProjectId` is also 2.

Query edited